# jQuery Accordion Links Don't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            // Clickable Dropdown
            $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
            $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
            $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
                $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
                $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(document).click(function() {
                if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
                    $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<div class="click-nav">
    <ul class="no-js">
        <li><a class="clicker"><span id="profile">Drop down</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1. Drop down works perfect when clicked but it slides up either accordion is clicked or webpage at any other point the accordion slides up.
2. The links in drop down don't work, they appear on left bottom of webpage when anchors are mouse over but accordion slides up and page does not redirect on click.

Comment: can u run the code on fiddle?

Comment: No the JS part is not working on fiddle but the drop down of accordion is working perfect within my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're telling the accordion to slide up every time the document is clicked.  This jQuery slips in every time the links are clicked and executes first, closing the accordion and breaking the links.  You really should use some other handle to make the accordions slide up and put that as the jQuery selector instead of `$(document)`.  In fact, I would handle the opening and closing of the accordion in the same function.

Edit: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9c6b7ya/1/)

Comment: My jQuery skills are not so good, this is copy-paste code with 100s of attempt reached to this extent, I can not make any further changes as it goes beyond my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I've added a fiddle.  Some jQuery tips--First: I think that you're trying to do too much with jQuery; use css too.  Second: Feel free to add selectors in the DOM, it will make your javascript life so much easier.

Comment: It is working awesome in fiddle you share but not working at my project, event I have made a single html document with inner css and js but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine and there is no mistake either.

1) The dropdown toggles as you have written the code to toggle it with slideToggle(200) and it toggles also when you clicked on the document anywhere provided the dropdown is visible.

2) links are working fine they are following the path.

The only caution you have to take is not to click anywhere in parallel to the "Drop down" text as the "click-nav" div is 100% width.